# How is "make" used when talking about a type of car?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, adjectives

> Those are all cars make Chevrolet.
> Those are all make Chevrolet cars.
> Those are all Chevrolet make cars.

Are *any* of these syntactically correct English phrases?

Comment: Either "Those are all Chevrolets" or "Those are all Chevrolet cars" would be idiomatic.

Comment: You can look up: a make of car.

Comment: "The make of all those cars is Chevrolet." Not that idiomatic, but if you want to use "all those' and "make", it's the only way I can think of doing it.

Comment: I actually know about the idiomatic way to do that and this is why I didn't originally post here but have been moved. I would like to know if any of those would be *technically* correct.

Comment: The first is flat out wrong and the second sounds really odd because we'd just say: those are all Chevrolets.

Comment: 'Those are all Chevrolet-made cars.' uses a compound adjective in a standard way, but the earlier suggestions (in comments) are more idiomatic in everyday contexts. The two suggested sentences (particularly the first) sound like they belong in the military with their unusual phrasing. They're certainly outlandish in everyday parlance (and how can Chevy cars have a military connection?)

Answer (score 1):

*Make* in this sense is a noun, and quite close in meaning to *brand*.

So your first two are ungrammatical.

Your 3. is just about possible, in the same sense of *Those are all Chevrolet brand cars*; but it's not idiomatic in any version of English I am aware of. I don't know an explanation for this: it's just how the word happens (not) to be used.